# ssh client side audit

Tags: ssh, audit

Now I am trying to design some ssh audit framework. I want to log all the user inputs.

I have found on the server site, logs(e.g, bash history) are kept and we can even use auditd to capture the user actions after he/she opened a file with vi.

My question is that is it possible to audit it on the SSH client side? Is there any ssh option or packages available? I haven't found any~

Thanks,

Comment: you don't want to audit anything on the client side. You have no control on what is going on the client side.

Comment: @Jakuje I think you are generally right and normally it's not good to do it on client side. But it's still doable if  the tool used by clients are provided by me and I have some mechanism (e.g.,hash checking) to make sure they didn't hack into it:)

Comment: There is nothing like that in the `openssh`, but as far as I know, something similar might work with ssh.com

Comment: @Jakuje Thx. Their product CryptoAuditor is very helpful :)